# symfony test undefined function

Tags: symfony, testing

i have problem with my test. I don't know why my function is undefined. I add use statetment, phpstorm see this class. But when run test error with undefined.

```
   namespace tests\AppBundle\Parser;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use AppBundle\Parser\CommissionDataParser;

class CommissionDataParserTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testGroupOrdersByWeek()
    {

        $orders = [
            0 => [
                'date'  => '2016-01-10',
                'client_id'        => '2',
                'client_type'=> 'natural',
                'operation_type' => 'cash_in',
                'operation_sum'     => '200.00',
                'operation_currency'      => 'EUR',
            ],

            1 => [
                'date'  => '2016-01-05',
                'client_id'        => '1',
                'client_type'=> 'legal',
                'operation_type' => 'cash_out',
                'operation_sum'     => '300.00',
                'operation_currency'      => 'EUR',
            ],

            2 => [

                'date'  => '2016-01-11',
                'client_id'        => '1',
                'client_type'=> 'natural',
                'operation_type' => 'cash_out',
                'operation_sum'     => '30000',
                'operation_currency'      => 'JPY'
            ]
        ];


        $expected = [
            0 => [
                'date'  => '2016-01-05',
                'client_id'        => '2',
                'client_type'=> 'natural',
                'operation_type' => 'cash_in',
                'operation_sum'     => '200.00',
                'operation_currency'      => 'EUR',
            ],

            1 => [
                'date'  => '2016-01-10',
                'client_id'        => '1',
                'client_type'=> 'legal',
                'operation_type' => 'cash_out',
                'operation_sum'     => '300.00',
                'operation_currency'      => 'EUR',
            ],

            2 => [
                'date'  => '2016-01-11',
                'client_id'        => '1',
                'client_type'=> 'natural',
                'operation_type' => 'cash_out',
                'operation_sum'     => '30000',
                'operation_currency'      => 'JPY'
            ]
        ];

        $um = new CommissionDataParser();
        $result = $um->groupOrdersByWeek($orders);


        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result, '**** -->>>>> result array wrong');

    }
```

there is function that i want to test: i put small part of this class, for example

```
namespace AppBundle\Parser;


class CommissionDataParser
{
    public function getData($file)
    {
        $orders = $this->extractOrders($file);

        if (is_array($orders)) {
            $orders = $this->groupOrdersByWeek($orders);
        }

        // ...
    }


    public function extractOrders($file)
    {
        $orders = [];
        $data = [];
        //$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($file));

        if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                $num = count($row);

                if ($num !== 6) {
                    return 'Badly structured file';

                } else if ($num == 0) {
                    return 'file is empty';
                }

                $data[] = $row;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            $orders[] = [
                'date' => $row[0],
                'client_id' => $row[1],
                'client_type' => $row[2],
                'operation_type' => $row[3],
                'operation_sum' => $row[4],
                'operation_currency' => $row[5]
            ];
        }

        return $orders;
    }
```

Comment: can u paste here u code of CommissionDataParser?

Answer (score 0):

In first, you must check that your phpunit uses `app/autoload.php` as bootstrap. Open your `phpunit.xml.dist` file in your project root, and find this line:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="app/autoload.php"
>
```

If u see this line `bootstrap="app/autoload.php"` in your file, then all right.

Next, check that your file `CommissionDataParser.php` physically located in this directory `AppBundle\Parser`. Full path to this file must be `YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT\src\AppBundle\Parser\CommissionDataParser.php`

If you did everything correctly then it should work. At least I was able to run your code.

Comment: it was bootstrap="autoload.php" when i run with this path i have error with undefined function, if i add app/autoload.php , then i get Cannot open file "/var/www/symfony/app/app/autoload.php".

Comment: ok, at last, did you realy has `groupOrdersByWeek` method in `CommissionDataParser` class ?)))

Answer (score 0):

yes really have :) i take a picture for example : )

[image]

Comment: all works, i was have in to folders tests. How from my test when i create object my parser put object entity manager? because it need for class?